# Python List as List Index

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Really not sure the right question to ask for this, but is it possible to have a list as the index of a list?

Ex:

```
pixelAddr=[50,50] # list
img[pixelAddr[0], pixelAddr[1]]=[255,255,255] # This is the way I know

# Is something like this possible? I get syntax errors when I try it... 
img[*pixelAddr]=[255,255,255]
```

Btw, using python 3.7

Comment: A list cannot take a list as index, but numpy arrays work with lists or tuples (with different meanings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do: `img[pixelAddr[0], pixelAddr[1]]` you are actually just re-packing the indices as a **`tuple`** so that is really all you need:

```
pixelAddr=(50,50) # NOTE THESE ARE ROUND PARENTHASIS
img[pixelAddr]=[255,255,255]

# or 
pixelAddrList = [50,50]
img[tuple(pixelAddr)]=[255,255,255]
```

Comment: Do you have permission to edit the tags? If so, could you add a plain python tag to the question please?

Comment: @MadPhysicist ty for request and done :)

Comment: Thanks. Nice answer, but I did dupe-hammer the question (which I can't do if I add the tag myself :))

Comment: The tuple was the magic syntax! I have to wait 5 more minutes to accept the answer.